# Mudança htdocs Apache 24 no windows

Tags: php, apache

estou lendo muito por ai, inclusive páginas em inglês.

Mas nenhuma explicação dá certo. Ou dá certo e está faltando alguma coisa.

Estou querendo mudar a localização da pasta **htdocs** do **Apache24** para o disco D.

Então eu fiz:

```
#DocumentRoot "D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs"
#<Directory "D:\Trabalhos\host\htdocs">

DocumentRoot "C:\Program Files\Apache24\Apache24\htdocs"
<Directory "C:\Program Files\Apache24\Apache24\htdocs">
```

Pelo que podem ver as linhas antigas eu comentei.

Mas também fiz só com as novas.

```
DocumentRoot "C:\Program Files\Apache24\Apache24\htdocs"
<Directory "C:\Program Files\Apache24\Apache24\htdocs">
```

Resultado? Quando vou ver no **phpinfo()**

```
DOCUMENT_ROOT    C:/Program Files/Apache24/Apache24/htdocs
```

SIM: Eu reinicie o Apache primeiramente. Como não funcionou, reiniciei o windows: Nada!

Continua no mesmo lugar!

Falta aletrar algum outro local será?

Answer (score 0):

Ok! Não sei porque.

Mas após a quarta reinicialização do windows o Apache atualizou o `DirectoryRoot`

Obrigado a todos que ***quebraram suas cabeças*** tentando entender o problema!